# Cannot install mc using apt-get 

Tags: linux, installation, debian, aptitude, midnight-commander

I'm trying to install mc using apt-get:

> apt-get install mc

... and get the following error:

> Failed to fetch
>   http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mc/mc_4.6.2-2_i386.deb
>   404 Not Found [IP: 130.89.149.226 80]

Tried /etc/apt/sources.list, fetching specific version, tried -t, tried "man apt-get"... but I cannot get through this. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because apt's package index that lists particular *versions* of packages is out of date on your system: just update it with `sudo apt-get update`.